# dynamically display url link using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how I can dynamically display a link in the href of an html a tag. I currently have the below code that displays the values as I type but I would like to have this code display a click url in the a tag href.

Can someone please help?

**HTML form code:**

```
<input type="text" id="testTextareadestinationurl" autocomplete="off" size="57" maxlength="2500" name="destinationurl" class="required"/>
<span id='UrlDestinationurl'><?php echo  $destinationurl;?></span>
<a href="" target="_blank"><img src=""></a>
```

**javascript code:**

```
var testTextareadestinationurl = document.getElementById('testTextareadestinationurl');
testTextareadestinationurl.onkeydown = updateUrlDestinationurl;
testTextareadestinationurl.onkeyup = updateUrlDestinationurl;
testTextareadestinationurl.onkeypress = updateUrlDestinationurl;
function updateUrlDestinationurl() {
    document.getElementById('UrlDestinationurl').innerHTML = this.value || "";
}

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Assign an id to your <a> tag and set it's src attribute to whatever link you want. Jquery would make this easy

Answer (score 2):

You're basically missing this from your `updateUrlDestinationurl` function:

```
document.getElementById('anchorUrlDestinationurl').href = "http://" + this.value || "";
```

Assuming you give an id of 'anchorUrlDestinationurl' to your target `<a>` element.

Don't prepend "http://" depending on what you want to type into the input.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p4BUB/)

P.S. you don't need to handle all three of those keypress events but I assume your code is a subset of something...

Comment: Thank you. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Plymouth223  when i submit my form and click on the url link the link doesnt seem to work correctly. I have to delete some characters and retype the url in order for the image to click to the url. Any idea how i can fix that? I can try to provide my code.